# can't get bytes from IOUtils.toByteArray

Tags: java, byte, inputstream

I'm connected using a socket

```
s.connect(socketAddress, 0);
```

I get the InputStream

```
InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
```

reading the bytes using IOUtils

```
byte[] readByteArray=IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
for(int i=0;i<readByteArray.length;i++)
{
    Log.d(CONNECTION_TAG,""+readByteArray[i]);
}
```

however no output in my logcat! 
what's the problem?

Comment: Is there anything to be read on this socket?

Comment: And does the other end *close* the socket? (If not, `toByteArray` will be waiting to see the end of the stream...)

Comment: on the other end use outputStr.flush(); and or use it as `String s = new String(ByteArray)`;

Comment: @LutzHorn sure the socket works fine and I send the data through it

Comment: @BhargavModi: No, *don't* do that. a) it uses the platform default encoding; b) it won't give you anything useful for binary data

Comment: How do you know it works fine?

Comment: @JonSkeet so I have to close the socket for this ? I need to keep reading , I don't want the socket to be closed

Comment: Try to `read()` a `byte` from the socket.

Comment: @LutzHorn if I read the inputstream into a reagular byte array I get the data. however I want to use IOUtils because I don't want to set the byte array size in advance

Comment: By using `read()` you could tell  if reading from the socket works. Later you can switch to `IOUtils`.

Comment: @beginsheinyani: Well how would you expect `IOUtils` to know when to stop reading? There could be another byte about to arrive. Bear in mind that we have no idea what data you're putting down this socket. If you have some sort of message-oriented stream (with a length-prefix, for example), you should probably implement some code to read a single message from the stream.

Comment: @JonSkeet so how would you suggest reading a single message of unknown length from the stream?

Comment: @LutzHorn I did try read() and the socket works

Comment: Well how would you expect to know when the message has finished? It sounds like you've misunderstood the nature of streams - a single "message" could take multiple reads, or one read call could read multiple messages, and without any way of knowing where a message stops there's no inherent way of splitting the stream into messages.

Comment: @JonSkeet maybe I have misunderstood it. 
all I want is whenever I read x number of charachters , to put them in a byte array and do something with it . but I want the socket to stay open so then another y number of charachters arrive I do the same

Comment: Characters or bytes? They're not the same thing. And I thought you said you didn't know the length of the message (x and y in this case).

Comment: @JonSkeet x and y are unknown for me that's my point. I want to read unknown number of characters and convert them to a byte array later on

Comment: Okay, that's not normally how you'd phrase that then - "read x bytes" suggests that you *know x*. How is anything meant to know when it should stop reading from the stream and return the data to you? When it's read *any* data? When it's read *at least* 10 bytes? Again, I think you've misunderstood how streams work.